Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument , When search a string in MS word file in folder and it's subfolders
Basically, I am trying to use VBA to search for a string inside word files in a folder and sub-folders. 
I found the below macro, But it raises this error. 

Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

After debugging, the error is found on this line subFolder = Dir 
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub SearchWordFilesInFolder(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal searchText As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim wordApp As Object, wordDoc As Object
    Dim subFolder As String, myFile As String, i As Long
    
    ' Initialize Word application
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = False ' Set to True if you want to see Word
    
    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    myFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.doc*")
    
    i = 1
    
    Do While myFile <> ""
        ' Open the Word file
        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(folderPath & myFile)
        
        ' Search for the text
        With wordDoc.Content.Find
            .Text = searchText
            If .Execute Then
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = folderPath & myFile:     i = i + 1
            End If
        End With
        
        ' Close the Word file
        wordDoc.Close False
        
        ' Get the next file in the folder
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Close Word application
    wordApp.Quit
    
    ' Loop through each subfolder and call the function recursively
    subFolder = Dir(folderPath & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While subFolder <> ""
        If subFolder <> "." And subFolder <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(folderPath & subFolder) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                SearchWordFilesInFolder folderPath & subFolder & "\", searchText
            End If
        End If
        subFolder = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Sub StartSearch()

    Dim folderPath As String, searchText As String
    
    ' Set the folder path where your Word files are located
    folderPath = "\\Path of Parent Folder\"
    
    ' Set the search text
    searchText = "Converted"
    
    ' Call the search function
    SearchWordFilesInFolder folderPath, searchText
    
End Sub


Which Operating system are you using?

@CHill60 , Windows 10 x64

Then your folder name cannot contain quotes - those characters are illegal in folder names for any version of Windows.
It could be that you are too deep into the recursion or possibly you have opened too many Word objects without clearing them up fully.
Rather than usnig DIR have you considered using the FSO?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object

You can't nest Dir recursively like that, it doesn't stack. Use FSO instead.

Here's a non-recursive approach to searching subfolders, using Dir() and a Collection as a queue:
'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim f, fldr, colFiles As New Collection, colSub As New Collection

    colSub.Add startFolder

    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        fldr = colSub(1) 'next folder to process
        colSub.Remove 1  'remove from queue
        If Right(fldr, 1) <> "\" Then fldr = fldr & "\"
        'Debug.Print "Processing: " & fldr

        f = Dir(fldr & filePattern, vbNormal)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            'Debug.Print , fldr & f
            colFiles.Add fldr & f
            f = Dir()
        Loop
        
        f = Dir(fldr & "*", vbDirectory)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            If f <> "." And f <> ".." Then
                If (GetAttr(fldr & f) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                    colSub.Add fldr & f
                End If
            End If
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function

I think it's almost twice as fast as similar code using FileSystemObject...
